# How do I change or use variables in the class where my object was created?

Tags: java, oop

I have a Breakout game in Java. The Game object is declared in a socket endpoint. The Game class has a Ball object for example. How would I change properties from the Game class in my Ball class?

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is for this.

Code to understand:

```
public class Game {

    private Ball ball;
    private int score;

    public Game(){
        this.ball = new Ball(startLocationBall,10,2);
    }
}
```

Now I want to change score from my Ball class when it hits a brick.

Comment: Use getters & setters?

Comment: But how do I call Game.setScore from my Ball class then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the ball object with a reference to the corresponding Game object.
This way you can call game.setScore() from the ball class. (You should add a setter and a getter for the score variable) ;)

```
public class Ball{

    private Game game;

    public Ball(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }    

}
```

Comment: Are these the same game objects though? Wouldn't it be a copy of the first one?

Comment: No, the Game object will be passed by reference :)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thanks!